# Does .toggleClass not work with those inside nest?

Tags: jquery, nested

I use $().toggleClass(); to display and hide inventory, but I notice that those feature inside the nest of the container does not have its property applied at all.

for example HTML

```
   <div id="container">

      <div id="inventory" class="hidden">

        <p>Hello There</p>

      </div>

   </div>
```

and then Jquery/Javascript

```
else if (button == 'Inventory') {
    
    inventoryWipe();
    lookinventory();
    $("#container").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#inventory").toggleClass("hidden");

  }
```

There is a button, you click on it, it hides the container but inventory is still hidden, by the rule of toggleClass, it should invert both of them, so it will show inventory instead of a container. I assume that since Inventory is nesting inside the container, it no longer works.

Bonus question, I use `$("something").insertBefore("#inventory");` but it does not work for this as it adds element before inventory element rather than put it inside the inventory, how do I do that?

Comment: When an element is hidden, everything inside it is also hidden.

Comment: append() or prepend() to insert inside element. All the insertion methods are easily found in the jQuery api docs

Comment: Okay, thank you two, I will have to make a separate container and stuff inside it then. and thank you for one that will allow me to insert inside it. I could have sworn I try those two but end up with the same result as insertBefore() and insertAfter().